# Change Description character limit under Pages Library under Sharepoint Online programatically using @pnp/sp

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp, sitepages, sharepoint-page

I need enable option allow unlimited length programmatically using @pnp/sp in document library for description field.

Please check below screenshot for more details,
[image]

Also, I need to get likes and comments of pages using @pnp/sp.
Do I need to make separate calls for each pages for get likes and comments as per the below reference links?

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/comments-likes/#get-page-comments

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/comments-likes/#likeunlike

Or Is there any alternative in @pnp/sp ?

Thanks